# Why can I receive a 7mb video text but it is too large to forward?

Tags: sms, video

Problem: I have an A51 Samsung. I can't forward a text video that was attached and text to me from another A51 (my wife's).

What I tried: I tried saving smaller since I cannot trim it.

It just doesn't make sense to me that my wife can attach and text me a 7 MB video but I can't do the same, having the same identical phone.

Comment: This could just be a bandwidth limitation. Is this a single message recipient, a group with messages sent as MMS, or a group message sent as a group of SMS (i.e. singlular texts to many people, each harboring the same video?) These are all possibilities integral to texting apps, and can be set with differing settings/priorities per user or device.

Comment: What is the complete error message? Could you provide a screenshot? Might also be the mobile carrier's restriction, do both of you using the same carrier and same plan?

Comment: Do you both have the same service provider?  If so, it's possible you just married up. ;)

Comment: @wbogacz, and everyone.  --  This is just a single message I want to send to a single recipient. A screenshot would simply just be an image of the video I want to forward that I received. My wife and I have the same exact phone and carrier. We bought them at the same time.... liked "it's possible you just married up." Ha! :)   -- I'm open to any user settings if that is a possible solution. I'm just not sure what that would be.

Comment: Are you both using the same messaging app? Samsung has their own that is different from the standard Android app.

Comment: @girolamous Yeah, we are. Just the standard "Messges" app.